Android Studio Emulator Issue "System UI is not responding"
Android Emulator [AVD- Pixel 6 API 34] is showing "System UI is not responding".
I have done all the troubleshooting like Wipe Data, Cold Boot, Deleting it and installing again, disabling Intel GPU and Enabling Nvidia GPU alone but the issue is not resolving. My system property is 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor.

Try x86 only ABI option when selecting a system image. Not x86_64.

I have faced the same issue, I am using MAC OS Ventura with 13+.
Below are the steps which I followed and found it's working fine.

Update MAC OS to newer version
Update android build tools
Gave super user access rights to android-tools folder
did invalidate and reset Android studio
Removed all emulators
repeat step 4
create new emulator with 6.0 with SDK version 33
repeat step 4
launch emulator separately
then run the app

